# Contains без размещения на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

мы можем создать зону

```
let obj = new ymaps.Circle(geometry); // or Polygon
```

мы можем разместить его на карте

```
map.geoObjects.add(obj);
```

и можем проверить точку на вхождение в эту зону

```
obj.geometry.contains([lat,lon]);
```

вопрос: каким образом проверить вхождение точки в зону без размещения зоны на карте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не добавлять круг на карту, то вычислить вхождение не получится.

Варианты:
1. Можно задать opacity: 0 кругу (чтобы его не было видно) и добавлять и удалять круг при каждом вычислении вхождения.
2. Можно вычислять через containsPoint отсюда https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/util.pixelBounds-docpage/ если устроит, что это будет не круг, я прямоугольник.

Comment: А почему надо добавлять и сразу удалять область? Как она будет мешать, если просто останется прозрачной?